# Android BLE API strange behavior

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I connect to my Bluetooth Low Energy device like it's described in : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

1. I get device:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {

       if(device.getName().startsWith("BLE device")){
           mDevice = device;
           mDevice.connectGatt(RGBLight.this, false, bgc);


       }
   }
   ```
2. Getting a gatt from Device:

   ```
   public void onConnectionStateChange(final android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
       if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
          //My app should keep connection to the BLE device as long as app lives.
           RGBLight.this.gatt = gatt;
           gatt.discoverServices();
       }
   }
   ```

3.When gatt is connected and services are discovered i'm trying to send a messages queue to the characteristic.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (mService == null)
                mService = gatt.getService(UUID_SERVICE);
            if (mCharacteristic == null)
                mCharacteristic = mService.getCharacteristic(UUID_CHAR);



            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){


                int r = Color.red(colorParsed);
                int g = Color.green(colorParsed);
                int b = Color.blue(colorParsed);
                int br = Color.blue(brParsed);

                mCharacteristic.setValue(new byte[] { COMMAND_SET_RGBW, (byte) r, (byte) g, (byte) b, (byte) br, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
                gatt.writeCharacteristic(mCharacteristic);

                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);   
                }               
            }


    }).start();
```

When i run this code, most of commands are missed. Execution speed is about 1 command per second. And there is an error in LogCat:

```
     06-23 12:34:25.627: E/bt-btif(18002): already has a pending command!!
```

This low speed worsens user experience of my app.

I investigated a few days and found very interesting behavior. If I start the app and quickly send message queue, it works fast.(1 command per 100ms). But after 10-15 seconds after start it begin to slow down and error message occures again:

```
     06-23 12:34:25.627: E/bt-btif(18002): already has a pending command!!
```

Maybe someone already faced with a such problem and there is a way to reset a message queue  with Android API or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST wait for onCharacteristicWritten before you continue or you flood the buffers. That gatt.write characteristic returns merely means it is on its way through the ble stack and air.

Comment: question is: Why during the first 10-15 seconds after connection there are no problems with buffers and I can write characteristic on high speed. But after that time, even if i didn't write any characteristic, i get an error message. And is it possible to reach the "first 10 second" behavior permanently. Thanks